# Using Solr/Lucene for searching non-text tables?

Tags: full-text-search, postgresql-9.1, feature-comparison

I am creating a web application to retrieve subsets of one large (4m rows) table. The 4m rows only change once a year. The table has 200+ columns of types boolean and numeric. It has no text columns.

Users will query subsets of this table for download.

I am rather familiar with the PostgreSQL 9.1 database, and my plan is:

- The webapp will help the user to create queries like "WHERE a=3 AND b=true AND c>300"
- The DB will have proper indexes for the most-used columns.

NOW.. I read here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053050/why-is-solr-so-much-faster-than-postgres:

> I recently switched from Postgres to Solr and saw a ~50x speed up in our queries. The queries we run involve multiple ranges, and our data is vehicle listings. For example: "Find all vehicles with mileage < 50,000, $5,000 < price < $10,000, make=Mazda..."

So now I wonder: **Will/can Solr, Lucene, ElasticSearch, Amazon Cloud Search searches be faster than PostgreSQL even if no full-text search is involved?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will/can Solr/Lucene searches be faster than PostgreSQL even if no
>   full-text search is involved?

Yes. As per your quoted example, it can be many times faster than a relational database for certain use cases. Not surprising really.

`Solr` is a search engine. `PostgreSQL` is a relational database engine.

`Solr` is built from the ground up to do one thing well, search. It cannot do the work of a transactional database system. `Solr` cannot guarantee ACID compliance, it does not efficiently manage concurrency, it is not a viable candidate for OLTP workloads.

`PostgreSQL` is built from the ground up to do one thing well, transactional processing. It can also do a reasonable job of providing search type facilities but that is not its primary role. It does guarantee ACID compliance, it does manage concurrency, it is not a search engine.

> The 4m rows only change once a year.

In which case you probably don't need the key features of a relational database engine.

You need a search engine. Could be [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), [Amazon Cloud Search](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/) or one of a dozens others but first and foremost it will be a search platform, not a relational database.

Comment: Thanks! I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814050/solr-or-database with a similar answer: Use each for what it is best for.

Comment: According to [this post](http://charlesnagy.info/it/postgresql/postgresql-full-text-search-vs-solr) (from June 2015) Postgres can be faster than Solr. This reply being a couple of years old, maybe things have improved in Postgres?